# Helical Gear Module 0.85

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

I am trying to install an optical encoder that interfaces with a conveyor belt's drive shaft. The current setup is as follows: The central DC motor has a left-handed helical gear. This central helical gear interfaced with a right-handed plastic helical gear with the following dimensions:

Teeth #: 38 teeth

Outer Diameter: 34 mm

Bore: 6mm

I calculated the Module as OD/# of teeth + 2, ignoring the cosine of the helical angle (most vendors ignore it anyways). This gives me a module of 0.85, which is very uncommon, and I can't find anything online like it!

Here are my questions:

1. Am I calculating the Module correctly?
2. Is 0.85 Module very uncommon where it's most likely custom-made? or am I just looking in the wrong places?
3. Could an imperial-to-metric conversion be the problem with why I am not getting a whole number for the module?

Thanks!

Comment: Honestly. look harder. Really hard. It may not be easy or cheap as gears are infinite and varied, and many are not common stock while others are custom. You are already into rare gear types (helical), and a plastic one at that. An unusual combination. I'm surprised you even managed to find plastic helical gears in for sale, to be honest so I am not surprised you can't find a matching pitch. You might need it custom made.

Comment: @jsotola, I am so sorry, not sure why my questions did not get published earlier on. I edited my post and added my questions. Thanks for your willingness to help!

Comment: @DKNguyen, thank you! This gives me a good perspective on how uncommon this might be. I can now stop banging my head against the wall and go about 3D printing my own or something. I am not experienced with gears and was hoping that there is some sort of standard that I don't know about.

Comment: You might have calculated the module wrong. It is not OD/# teeth, it is the pitch diameter / number of teeth. The pitch diameter is not the same as OD, it is somewhere in between the OD and diameter at the root of the teeth.

Answer (score 0):

Considering how rare this helical gear might be, I decided that I needed to make my own. Luckily, I can get away with a plastic version so I 3D printed a design that I made from scratch. It worked!

Comment: If you want to go convert a 3D printed object to metal: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJOOLH9ZP2I

Comment: @DKNguyen, this is super useful, thank you for sharing!